# using or case in Query with sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

i need to search with 2 varibiles  name , phone
and with spcific stat for the two cases
like :

case 1
spcific name with it's stat

case 2
spcific phone with it's stat

which right method to do this

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable1' WHERE name='"+thename+"' or phone='"+thephone+"' and stat LIKE 'o-%'";
```

or

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable1' WHERE name='"+thename+"' and stat LIKE 'o-%'"
+" or phone='"+thephone+"' and stat LIKE 'o-%'";
```

thanks for you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

second one is the better. `AND` has priority over `OR`. For more precedence related question checkout this = [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_operators_precedence.htm#:~:text=Here%2C%20operators%20with%20the%20highest,%2C%20LIKE%2C%20BETWEEN%2C%20IN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_operators_precedence.htm#:%7E:text=Here%2C%20operators%20with%20the%20highest,%2C%20LIKE%2C%20BETWEEN%2C%20IN).